Какого типа это сложноподчиненное предложение :
Я готов выполнить эту работу до
завтра, лишь бы мне никто не мешал.

ОТВЕТ
Я готов выполнить эту работу до завтра, лишь бы мне никто не мешал.
В предложении выражены условные отношения со значением пожелания, в качестве союзного средства использована частица ЛИШЬ БЫ. Во второй части предложения глагол употреблен в форме сослагательного наклонения.
Семантика сообщения: Я готов выполнить работу, при условии если мне не будут мешать.
ЛИШЬ. I. II. союз,  4. (в сочет. с частицей бы: лишь бы). Присоединяет предложение, выражающее пожелание. Я приду, л. бы тебя увидеть.
ДОПОЛНИТЕЛЬНАЯ ИНФОРМАЦИЯ

Условные отношения возможны в СПП или БСП.

В СПП такие варианты:


(1) Я готов  выполнить эту работу до завтра, если  мне никто не будет мешать. Реальное условие, нет сослагательного наклонения.
(2) Я бы выполнил эту работу до завтра, если бы мне никто не мешал. Ирреальное (контрфактическое условие): помешали, вот и не выполнил. Частица БЫ как показатель сослагательного наклонения в обеих частях предложения.

БСП. Я готов выполнить работу, лишь бы не мешали. Этот вариант ближе к заданному.

В учебнике по грамматике есть похожий пример для БСП: Ужин не нужен, был бы обед.  Или так: Ужин не нужен, лишь бы был обед.

Если считать, что это БСП, то частица ЛИШЬ БЫ используется в качестве союза, но союзом не является (то есть не меняет вид предложения).

Таким образом, решение относительно СПП и БСП может быть разным. В школьной практике допускается считать предложение СПП, а частицу ЛИШЬ БЫ союзом.


